# What does "Q1/2/3/4+year" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've started to see a lot this use:
Q1 2016
Q4 2016
But what does it exactly mean? What does Q stand for?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Q#Abbreviation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quarter.

Each year has four quarters.

Quarter 1 (Q1) runs from the 1st of January to the 31st of march.
Quarter 2 (Q2) runs from the 1st of April to the 30th of June.
Quarter 3 (Q3) runs from the 1st of July to the 30th of September.
Quarter 4 (Q4) runs from the 1st of October to the 31st of December.

For example we are currently in Q3.

I mainly hear this term used in business, where it's a useful way of dividing the year into sensible chunks.

Comment: Quarters, when used by businesses for reporting purposes, do not necessarily follow those exact divisions but can differ from company to company. So the precise date that Q1 ends and Q2 beings it is not universal.